# Check template type in struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I want to define additional variables in a struct based on the type in template, something like this:

```
template<typename CONFIG>
struct Test
{
    int a;
    int b;

    if (std::is_same<CONFIG, MyClass>::value) 
    {
        // additional variables if the CONFIG type is MyClass
        int c;
        int d;
    }

    // functions
    void func()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        if (std::is_same<CONFIG, MyClass>::value)
        {
            c = 0;
            d = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can't modify the contents of a class/struct at run-time. It has to be compile-time constant.

Comment: you could use template specialization, but not using a template but simply defining a seperate `MyClassTest` that has the additional members would achieve the same with less complications

Comment: Thanks all! it's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This is a use case for template specialization.  You have a primary template like

```
template<typename CONFIG>
struct Test
{
    int a;
    int b;

    // functions
    void func()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
};
```

and then a specialization for `MyClass` like

```
template <>
struct Test<MyClass>
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

    // functions
    void func()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Depending on how the structure of the templated type is exactly one could reduce code duplication by letting `Test<MyClass>` inherit from `Test<T>` for some `T` (here `void` would work for example). In more difficult cases (where `CONFIG` is actually used for example) one could create a templated base class that contains the code that is common to all template specifications.

Answer (score 2):

A variant that follows your pseudo-code a bit more (not saying that it is a better approach than the other answer):

```
template<typename CONFIG>
struct TestAdditionalMembers {};

template<>
struct TestAdditionalMembers<MyClass>
{
    int c;
    int d;
};

template<typename CONFIG>
struct Test : TestAdditionalMembers<CONFIG>
{
    int a;
    int b;

    // functions
    void func()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        if constexpr(std::is_same<CONFIG, MyClass>::value)
        {
            this->c = 0;
            this->d = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

The additional members are provided through inheritance and explicit specialization of the class template. Since `c` and `d` are not dependent names, but only exist for certain template parameters, you will need to refer to them with `this->c`, etc. (`this` is always a dependent name).

Inside a function the condition needs to be checked by a `if constexpr`, since at-runtime check would be too late. (The code inside the `if` must compile even if the condition is always false.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on walnuts answer, you could collect all your conditional actions and member variables in a specialization that you inherit if you want to avoid type traits and constexpr-if's.

```
template<typename T>
struct completions {
    void func_completion() {} // does nothing
};

template<>
struct completions<MyClass> {
    int c;
    int d;
    void func_completion() {
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
    }
};

template<typename CONFIG>
struct Test : completions<CONFIG> {
    int a;
    int b;

    // functions
    void func() {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        this->func_completion();
    }
};
```